# CodeIgniter core not available when using MY_Controller

Tags: codeigniter

I am using `core/MY_Controller.php` and changed all my controllers to extend `MY_Controller` instead of `CI_Controller`. Now all the 'core' functions from CodeIgniter do not work on my regular controllers, for example: autoloaded models give an `Undefined property` error, and things like `$this->load->...` are not working aswell.

**`core/MY_Controller.php`**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $test = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->test = "test";

    }
}
```

I initiate all my controllers with this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dashboard extends MY_Controller {
```

Comment: I think you need to write ```require``` at start of your file.

Comment: Hope you have used `parent::__construct();` in Base_Controller's   `__construct()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `__construct()` method in a class extending some other class, then you almost always need to call the parent constructor from the child.

Try this one simple addition to your constructor.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->test = "test";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this first in the my controller

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data['test'] = "test";

    }
}
```

Then create a variable like `public $data = array()`

```
<?php


class Example extends MY_Controller 
{

    public $data = array();

    public function index() 
    {
        $this->load->view('example', $this->data);
    }

}
```

View

```
<?php echo $hello;?>
```